# CSS Dropdown Menu, Visible not working

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, visible

**EDIT:** Just incase anyone in the future finds this i found the solution was to change from using visibility: to display: , so in the code

visibiliy:hidden; becomes display:none;
visibiliy:visible; becomes display:block;

Have not ever found out exactly why it visibility doesn't work on the 4th nesting but atleast this appears to fix it

Hi Guys,

I am currently working with a dropdown menu that is created using some CSS and lists. It is working fine but for some reason the 4th level of this menu is not listening to the visibility:hidden; command. According to element inspector The element is listed as being enabled but it is not actually doing it.

An example is here: http://dev.hutchup.com/test/css-dropdown.htm

I wont past code as it is too log and can be see at the link above

As you can see the first level 2 link when hovered over displays level's 3 and 4 when it should only display 3, and then when an li in 3 is rolled over it will display 4th level.

I know there are many easier ways to do this/ prebuilt thing but i need to do it this way so that i can use the ACL component for joomla and have menu items not display .

Ive spent hours and cant get it fixed so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this many levels of nesting is scary business and in this day and age probably better handled by some simple JavaScript with fallback (especially if it's tons of nested levels), although I did notice two things ;

- It looks to me that you're not specifying any styles for the fourth level. You may want to add a few to see if that is your problem.
- You've got some CSS that looks
  like this ;

---

```
   .moduletable_topmenu ul.menu li.item69 a {
    height: 2.5em;
   }
   */

   /*
   .moduletable_topmenu ul.menu li.item89 {
    height: 3.7em;
   } 

   .moduletable_topmenu ul.menu li.item89 a {
    height: 2.5em;
   }
```

---

These `li.item[n]` items are either leftover from something else or some future ideas not implemented, but they certainly do not apply to the menu in question.

Comment: Yeah i know its messy but its outputted by a CMS and its the cleanest way to do it (atleast its not tables like some options available :( )